# function checkRequest post

Tags: php, mysql, function, mysqli

I am trying to use a function to check post data agaist mysqli_real_escape_string.

Code

```
function checkRequest($key){
    $servername = "localhost";
    $username = "johndoe";
    $password = "1234";
    $database = "anydb";

    $key = $_POST[$key];

    // Create connection
    $conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password, $database);
    $key = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $key);
    mysqli_close($conn);
    return $key;  
}

$client = checkRequest('client');
```

I am getting

```
Notice: Undefined index: client in /home/www/entry_action.php on line 52
```

I cant seem to get this to work, looking to find what I did wrong... :-(

Comment: So i'm guessing `$key = 'client'`.  This notice is saying that `$_POST['client']` doesn't exist.

Comment: Yes $key in this test is client

Comment: $client = checkRequest('client');

Comment: So 'client' isn't in your post data.  This is a very strange function though.  What are you trying to accomplish with using real escape string like this?

Comment: I am trying to run all post data through mysqli_real_escape_string to prevent someone from messing up the database by using a ' or anything like that

Comment: The only time you should be using `mysqli_real_escape_string` is when you're putting a variable into a SQL string. But you should avoid doing that, and instead use prepared queries with `bind_param()`.

Comment: You shouldn't open and close the database connection in every function. Open it once when your script starts, and reuse that connection for everything you do.

Comment: Look at the procedural example here: http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php (since it seems like you're used to procedural).  I'd recommend learning OOP, but maybe take one step at a time.

Comment: I have never used bind_param(), I am trying to makesure that an entry does not mess up the database...

Comment: Prepared statements are the way to go, using placeholders like `?` in the prepared statement, then binding the variables safely using a bind_param call.  Ditch this function.  Insert example with multiple placeholders: http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php

Comment: Why don't you just try `$client = checkRequest($_POST["client"]);`. And remove `$key = $_POST[$key];` inside your function. Lets see what will happen.